# Respond to someone reviewing my suggested edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently made a revision to [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34462/best-order-of-heuristics-for-filtering-gift-suggestion-search-results).

It was a substantial revision because the OP had posted an answer to the question that should have been an edit to the question. I flagged that answer and it was removed really quickly but not before I'd copied and pasted the text into my edit view. So my revision included the OP's edit.

I checked in on the review status of my revision and saw that one of the reviewers rejected it with this note `This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost.`

As I don't have enough points to review edits or flags, I don't know if the reviewer was able to see that I had incorporated the OP's deleted answer in my edit. I wanted to be able to tell the reviewer that, but there is no way to respond to a reviewer.

Now, I understand that allowing everyone to respond to every review might get a little crazy and mods have a lot to deal with already, but maybe once a user has a certain number of points and/or reviews under their belt, allow an option to respond to a "Rejected" review? Or open up a specific Chat room for that purpose? Again, only available with a certain number of points/accepted reviews.

Comment: for reference, for answers like that where they should be an edit not an answer, I'd just through a moderator flag saying that; mods get a button that lets us convert self-answers to edits for just this sort of occasion

Comment: Yeah, I flagged it as "not an answer". When I checked the question and the answer was deleted, it wasn't added into the question, so I just did it myself. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good idea.  This would be a great addition and something that I can't see being abused.

The worst that I can imagine would be someone responding abusively at the reviewer, in which case the reviewer can simply ignore them.  We're all adults, I'm sure we have the ability to ignore trolls and idiots.

Answer (score 2):

I like this suggestion.  It might also be useful to strengthen the feedback loop in the opposite direction.  When I review an edit, sometimes I'd like to send a brief notification to the person who submitted it, things like:

It's also beneficial to move hyperlinks into the body text. 

or 
I think you changed the OP's meaning in the third paragraph, so I've edited your edit. 

or 
Wow! This is a very thorough edit.  Thanks for being so thoughtful.